# Escaping double quotes

Tags: javascript, escaping

I have this code snippet -

```
function updateUserSettings() {
    var cat;
    <logic:iterate id="category" name="studyData" property="categories">
        cat = dojo.byId("<%=category%>");
    </logic:iterate>
    ........
    ........
}
```

I want to escape double quote in `<%=category%>` value, but I can't use  tag to do that.

Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to `escape` % to %25 in string ?

Comment: In Javascript \ is used to escape any special character.

Comment: try with single quote `cat = dojo.byId('<%=category%>');`

Comment: yeah. something like that. Because I tried `<%=category.replace("\"", "\\\"")%>` and I got Servlet Exception

Comment: If I use single quote, then I won't be able to escape it.

Comment: Yes, it is a JSP file

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid Scriptlet and use JSTL or expression like `${category}`

You don't need to escape double quote use single quote around it like

```
cat = dojo.byId('${category}');
```

because JavaScript supports both double and single quotes for string.

---

**EDIT:**

You can use [`JSTL fn:replace() Function`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_replace.htm) to replace all occurrences of a string with another string.

For example:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
...

<c:set var="string1" value="This is first String."/>
<c:set var="string2" value="${fn:replace(string1,'first', 'second')}"/>

<p>Final String : ${string2}</p>
```